# Tablesorter append data from AJAX,but tablesorterPager size fail

Tags: ajax, tablesorter

Tablesorter version:  2.22.3

I used the AJAX Get data from Server side,but finally the table row always 10.
P.S. tablesorterPager size property already set 9999
The table row will display all the data.
HTML and JS is

```js
$(function () {
var gv_table;
 gv_table= $("#Info").tablesorter({
                theme: 'blue',
                sortList: [[0, 0]],
                widthFixed: true,
                widgets: ['zebra', 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders'],
                widgetOptions: {
                    columnSelector_container: '#ColumnSel',
                    columnSelector_columns: {

                    },
                }
            })
            .tablesorterPager({
                // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
                container: $("#infopager"),
                size: 9999,
                output: 'Showing: {startRow} to {endRow} (Total:{totalRows})'
            });
});
 $('#btnQuery').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../Handler/DataSrcHandler.ashx?TableName=UserInfo",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        DataSrc: $("#SelEnviro").val(),
                        Datakey: $("#txtUserKey").val()
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#info tbody').empty().append(response);
                        $('#info').trigger('update');
                    }
                });
};
```

```html
<div id="infopager" class="pager" style="width:180px">
  <span style="width:180px;color:blue" class="pagedisplay"></span> 
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;width: 500px;height:150px" >
    <table id="Info" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>EngName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

ashx return message is like

```
<tr>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>Peter</td>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>0123456789</td>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>Boy</td>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>NA</td>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>A</td>
<td align='center' valign='top' nowrap>Peter</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you try to check page in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: Yes,I used the Firebug for chrome check it.and didn't show any error.

Comment: What is length of ajax data sent from server?